# ImportError: No module named url

Tags: python-3.5

when i run the the given code in `prepare_dataset.py` whose code is below as
`from urllib.request
 import urlopen
 import json as simplejson`

`def main():
    # Download and prepare datasets
    list_generator = video_list_generator.Generator("playlists.json",   youtube_api_client.Client("AIzaSyD_UC-FpXbJeWzPfscLz9RhqSjKwj33q6A"))
    video_list = list_generator.get_video_list("piano")`

```
downloader = youtube_video_downloader.Downloader()
downloader.download_from_list(video_list)
```

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`

as `python prepare_dataset.py` in command-line then i get these errors

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prepare_dataset.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named request`

How can i get to run the above file any idea guys?

Comment: `python prepare_dataset.py` will use Python 2, in which `urllib.request` doesn't exist. Use `python3 prepare_dataset.py` instead.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Nonetheless, it is your exact problem, and the solution to it.

Comment: It was because of some silly mistakes in other files but finaaly it worked.Thanks @ZeroPiraeus